# the resource is not on the build path of java project with gradle groovy project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, groovy

I have imported the gradle project to Eclipse IDE. my gradle project having groovy files.When I click F3 on any file name it showing "The resource is not on the build path of java project". How can I fix this issue.please help me.FYI, I am not able to create new groovy file also in this project.

Comment: Have you tried a different IDE? Does it work from the command line?

Comment: I didnt tried different IDE. I didnt get, what do you mean by command line

Comment: am able to run gradle build and all from terminal. But not getting text assist in Eclipse IDE to code easily and open required file easily when reading code

Comment: Do you have the buildship plugin installed?

Comment: Yes @John. have installed buildship

Comment: I think we need to see some of the build file to answer some basic questions. Is the groovy plugin applied? Are the source sets correct? Things like that would be nice to see. Outside of that are there tests that run the code? Just because it builds doesn't mean it is a useful build.